# Spring MVC hibernate validations messages localization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have user locale stored somewhere in user profile. What I would like to have is to validate beans and get error massages in proper locale for particular user( set locale for validator before validation happens). What I have found for now that I can create locale in properties like this.

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=MyNotNullMessage 
validation.too.long=Sth
```

I just don't know how to add it to spring mvc (few locales) and how to change it before validation. Thanks in advance. Best Regards

Comment: You could use Spring MVC's internationalization if you need to validate form backing beans. Messages like this one: `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message` can be put in the usual `.properties` files that contain language specific strings.

Comment: You mean in resources? But how do I actually load them?And then change on demand?

Comment: I may not understand your problem correctly. If you just want to localize your Spring MVC application, including the validation messages, you could follow a tutorial like [this one](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/). Validation messages can be localized as any other string. They have predefined codes like `validation.constraints.NotNull.message`. If you want to do something more tricky, let's wait for other answers :)